# Changing the ListView shadow color and size

Tags: android, listview

When the list of items in a ListView is longer than the size of the ListView, you'll see a shadow indicating that there are more items above or below. By default, this shadow is black.  This is not desirable.

If I set the cacheColorHint to the following:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

The shadow will be transparent, showing the drawable I have set to the layout's background.  This is not desirable either.

I wish to simply change the color of the shadow to a lighter shade of black, or perhaps gray.  Is there a way to specify this?

Also, is there a way to change the shadow's size?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` you are setting this color to transparent. I don't know which color you want to use exactly, but try `android:cacheColorHint="#FF777777"`. I think it must work.

Comment: Wow... that is... embarrassing.  I'm half tempted to delete this question, lol.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't delete your question yet, you still had the remaining question of how to change the size. :)

You can use the method [`setFadingEdgeLength(int length)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFadingEdgeLength%28int%29) to do this; it's directly inherited from View, so just about any View should be able to use it.

Comment: you can use android:fadingEdgeLength="length" as well