# Remove clickability from ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, touch-event

I have a `ListView` and I want it to have shadows at top and bottom. For this I overlay two `ImageView`-s that contain the shadow images. Problem is, they receive touch events and `ListView` isn't scrolled when you try to start scrolling from top or bottom. I've tried setting `enabled`,`focusable`,`clickable` and `longClickable` properties to false, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting the imageview focusable="false" and set clickable="false" should work

Answer (score 1):

You can use listView.setClickable(false)

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set Image of the shadow as background of the listView?
Try something like this:

```
<ListView
...
android:backgroung="@drawable/shadow" 
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
>
...
</ListView>
```

Comment: I need another image as background of listview, also I want the shadow to be OVER the listview

Comment: ok well i don't know if it is possible what you want! Because you want control a view that is partially overlayed by another view (the ImageViews)!
If you want to modify shadow only try to see this question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627063/changing-the-listview-shadow-color-and-size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627063/changing-the-listview-shadow-color-and-size)

Comment: Exactly what I want, control view that is overlayed. Thanks for the link. Reading.